# Mule Dataweave Fixed Width File with header and footer

Tags: mule, flat-file, fixed-width, dataweave

I am working on a project where we receive a flat file but the first and last lines have information that does not fit the fixed width pattern. Is there a way to dataweave all of this information correctly and if possible put the header and footer into variables and just have the contents in the payload.

Example File

```
HDMTFSBEUP00000220170209130400           MT                                                     HD07
DT01870977         FSFSS   F3749261            CR00469002017020820170225                        0000
DT01870978         FSFSS   F3749262            CR00062002017020820170125                        0000
TRMTFSBEUP00000220170209130400  000000020000002000000000000043330000000000000                   0000
```

I know for CSV you can skip a line but dont see it with fixed width and also the header and footer will both start with the first 2 letters every time so maybe they can be filtered by dataweave?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to the [DataWeave Flatfile Schemas](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/dataweave-flat-file-schemas) documentation. There are several examples for processing several different types of data.

In this case, I tried to simplify your example data, and apply a custom schema as follow:

Example data:

```
HDMTFSBEUP00000220170209130400           
DT01870977         
DT01870978         
TRMTFSBEUP00000220170209130400
```

Schema/Flat File Definition:

```
form: FLATFILE
structures:
- id: 'test'
  name: test
  tagStart: 0
  tagLength: 2
  data:
  - { idRef: 'header' }
  - { idRef: 'data', count: '>1' }
  - { idRef: 'footer' }
segments:
- id: 'header'
  name: header
  tag: 'HD'
  values:
  - { name: 'header', type: String, length: 39 }
- id: 'data'
  name: data
  tag: 'DT'
  values:
  - { name: 'code', type: String, length: 17 }
- id: 'footer'
  name: footer
  tag: 'TR'
  values:
  - { name: 'footer', type: String, length: 30 }
```

The schema will validate the example data and identify based on the **tag**, the first 2 letters. The output will be grouped accordingly.

```
{
  "header": {},
  "data": [{}, {}],
  "footer": {}
}
```

Since the expected result is only the data, then just select it: `payload.data`.

Answer (score 0):

Use range selector to skip header and footer.

```
payload[1..-2] map {
   field1: $[0..15],
   field2: $[16..31]
   ...,
   ...
}
```

`[1..-2]` will select from 2nd line till the second last line in the payload.

`$[0..15]` will select from 1st column index to 16th index. `$[16..31]` select from 17th column index to 32nd index.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and the answer @sulthony h wrote needs a little tweak. I used these lines instead and it worked for me.

```
data:
  - { idRef: 'header', count: 1 }
  - { idRef: 'data', count: '>1' }
  - { idRef: 'footer', count: 1 }
```

"count" was missing from header and footer, and that was throwing an exception. Hope this helps.